# How to not use ObjectId() in node mongo native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

As `_id`'s get passed back and forth through REST API calls and other things that make it necessary for them to handled as strings, it can be annoying and error producing to have to wrap them as `ObjectIds` when querying or using as foreign keys in mongodb docs.

I would rather use uuid strings (using the npm uuid package).

Is there any way to change node mongodb to use string based id's by default when inserting a new object, and possibly also use the uuid generator function I specify?

Comment: maybe [Node.js + Mongoose / Mongo & a shortened _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524549/node-js-mongoose-mongo-a-shortened-id-field) will help.....

Answer (score 0):

The _id field of **MongoDB** can have any value you want as long as you can guarantee that it is unique for the collection. When your data already has a natural key, there is no reason not to use this in place of the auto-generated ObjectIDs.

By not using ObjectIDs, you also miss out on another convenience feature: An ObjectID also includes an unix timestamp when it was generated, and many drivers provide a funtion to extract it and convert it to a date. This can sometimes make a separate create-date field redundant.

But still you can use other field as primary key if you are facing issues. Just ensure you create a unique index on the field. You can generate the field when inserting your data.

```
db.collection.createIndex( <key and index type specification>, { unique: true } )
```

One example:

```
db.employees.createIndex( { "uuid": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```